# how can I center the image in my div? (so far the left border of my img is centered)

Tags: html, css

I have the following css code:

```
.tos{
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.tos-logo{
    width: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

and I want to put my logo (inside tos-logo div) in the center (horizontally). So far the left border is centered, how can I change it so the center of my image is directly in the middle?
here is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/pxzr679o/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `.tos-logo`s width makes the `div` 10px wide, but the `<img>` inside it still has its original dimensions - hence, it appears that the image is not centered. One way to fix that would be to let the `.tos-logo` have its original width that spans the whole screen (`<div>`s are block elements by default), and simply center align its text, like the following:

```
.tos-logo {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```css
.tos {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
}
.tos-logo {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="tos">
  <div class="tos-logo">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x120" alt="logologologo">
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam laoreet commodo magna sed blandit. Curabitur vehicula libero mi, ac molestie eros congue ut. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam pharetra felis sapien, at porta nunc hendrerit a. Integer augue ligula,
    pretium accumsan molestie nec, ornare at metus. Nunc in justo dignissim libero fringilla scelerisque ac eget tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi vitae diam eros. Vestibulum tempus elit in lorem scelerisque rhoncus.
    Etiam eu erat arcu. Vivamus at turpis dui. Nulla erat est, iaculis ac leo quis, luctus auctor ex. Nulla sapien ex, egestas quis risus ac, consequat congue odio. Integer tincidunt non metus quis dapibus. Vestibulum at mauris ante. Integer vestibulum
    in lectus in accumsan. Ut ligula velit, gravida in lacus in, commodo dignissim metus. Etiam luctus, orci dictum bibendum iaculis, augue dui ultricies risus, vel volutpat nisl ligula id massa. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    Duis eleifend est tristique turpis lacinia, sit amet gravida neque efficitur. Duis sapien sem, faucibus vitae scelerisque sed, commodo sed lectus.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.tos-logo` is a block element, which means that naturally it will take the entire width of its parent. If you don't set a fixed with and don't set the margins, you can simply use `text-align:center` to center any inline or inline-block elements contained within the block element.

## [<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/pxzr679o/3/)

```css
.tos{
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.tos-logo {
    text-align: center;
}
```